How to do Curve material texture, Geometry node to make imported svg look better?

I am import a world map SVG and want to make line between countries clear (it look like it merge when look from top), how can I highlight the outline ? with geometry node, or material shader
Another way I can think of is set different extrude value, can I do it with expression, or with geometry (I am trying to put random node in Geometry nodes but It put random value on Edge-curve of the object (I don't know how to call it, I have picture to show)
I also want to use gradient texture so map look more impress, how can I do it ?





Seems related: How to create border outline?

Thank you, its a good solution ! I just test it !
